# Перестали корректно отрабатывать сайты на VPS

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, администрирование, vesta

есть 2 сайта (wordpress), размещенные на впсе, час назад один из них начал отдавать 403 ошибку (права доступа), второй же - 500.
никаких действий с ними, как мне сказали, не производилось.
проверил права доступа: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

куда копать и в чём может быть загвоздка?
з.ы. 'reboot' и 'service apache2 restart' выполнял;
установлена vestaCP. кстати да, при попытке входа в вестуцп сталкиваюсь с такой ситуацией (авторизация не происходит):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

з.ы.ы. Linux http.dp.ua 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u4 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Очевидно, нужно читать логи

Comment: судя по всему острая нехватка места:
http://i.imgur.com/ia46dfX.png

что думаете?

Comment: Очеивдно, нужно освободить место :)